# 'TypeError: 'CompositeModel' object is not callable' when trying to fit a composite model

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, lmfit

I'm currently using `lmfit` to analyse some spectrum data, in particular, trying to fit a composite model which consists of a Gaussian and Linear model, a number of times (4 right now, might need to fit a few more in the future), and I keep getting the aforementioned error. Here's my current code:

```
gausmodel = GaussianModel()
linemodel = LinearModel()

params = linemodel.make_params(intercept=40, slope=0)
params += gausmodel.make_params(cen=100, sigma=10, amplitude=100)

model = gausmodel + linemodel

x = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(0, 351), columns=['Pixel Position'])
df = pd.concat([x, intens], axis=1)

# Create models for fitting
peak1 = model(prefix='p1_')
peak2 = model(prefix='p2_')
peak3 = model(prefix='p3_')
peak4 = model(prefix='p4_')

# Set hints for start parameters
params = peak1.make_params()

params['p1_cen'].set(value=80, min=70, max=100)
params['p1_sigma'].set(value=10, min=5, max=20)
params['p1_amplitude'].set(value=80, min=50, max=100000)
params['p1_intercept'].set(value=40, min=30, max=55)
params['p1_slope'].set(value=1, min=0.00001, max=5)

params.update(peak2.make_params())

params['p2_center'].set(value=150, min=140, max=160)
params['p2_sigma'].set(value=10, min=5, max=20)
params['p2_amplitude'].set(value=80, min=50, max=100000)
params['p2_intercept'].set(value=40, min=30, max=55)
params['p2_slope'].set(value=1, min=0.00001, max=5)

params.update(peak3.make_params())

params['p3_center'].set(value=200, min=180, max=220)
params['p3_sigma'].set(value=10, min=5, max=20)
params['p3_amplitude'].set(value=100, min=50, max=100000)
params['p3_intercept'].set(value=40, min=30, max=55)
params['p3_slope'].set(value=1, min=0.00001, max=5)

params.update(peak4.make_params())

params['p4_center'].set(value=250, min=230, max=300)
params['p4_sigma'].set(value=10, min=5, max=20)
params['p4_amplitude'].set(value=100, min=50, max=100000)
params['p4_intercept'].set(value=40, min=30, max=55)
params['p4_slope'].set(value=1, min=0.00001, max=5)

# Define peak model
fit_model = peak1 + peak2 + peak3

# Start fitting
init = fit_model.eval(params, x=df)
result = fit_model.fit(df['Intensity'], params, x=df['Pixel Position'])

print(result.fit_report())
```

I'm actually looking to continue using `lmfit` and not `scipy` as lmfit returns a number of useful statistics which I need, especially the reduced chi-square.

My dataframe consists of just two columns, one with the Pixel Position and the other with the Intensity, and have 4 peaks in them.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing what is a model class and what is a model instance.  Also, you don't need multiple lines - two lines add up to a line.

I recommend using something more like:

```
from lmfit.models import GaussianModel, LinearModel

peak1 = GaussianModel(prefix='p1_')
peak2 = GaussianModel(prefix='p2_')
peak3 = GaussianModel(prefix='p3_')
peak4 = GaussianModel(prefix='p4_')
model = peak1 + peak2 + peak3 + peak4 + LinearModel()

params = model.make_params(intercept=40, slope=0) 

params['p1_center'].set(value=80, min=70, max=100)
params['p1_sigma'].set(value=10, min=0)
params['p1_amplitude'].set(value=80, min=0)

params['p2_center'].set(value=150, min=140, max=160)
params['p2_sigma'].set(value=10, min=0)
params['p2_amplitude'].set(value=80, min=0)

params['p3_center'].set(value=200, min=180, max=220)
params['p3_sigma'].set(value=10, min=0)
params['p3_amplitude'].set(value=100, min=0)

params['p4_center'].set(value=250, min=230, max=300)
params['p4_sigma'].set(value=10, min=0)
params['p4_amplitude'].set(value=100, min=0)
```

Also, there really isn't much point to turning numpy arrays into dataframes here -- lmfit will just change them back to arrays.

```
x = p.arange(0, 351)
init = model.eval(params, x=x)
```

...

Comment: Hi! The problem is that the data I have basically has a large, channel-variable background, which was the reason why I wanted to add, to every Gaussian peak, an additional background. And I could you clarify your comment that I'm "confusing a model class and a model instance", I don't think I understood that line. But thanks for that comment on using numpy arrays for the x axis!

Comment: On "confusing model class with instance": The title of the question has the exception message "CompositeModel is not callable".  And you do indeed create an instance of a composite model (with "model=GaussianModel() + LinearModel()") and then call that repeatedly (with "peak1 = mode(prefix='p1_')").   That will indeed cause the exception you see because the instance of a model is not callable.    Instead, you should create an instance of a  model and then use that.